# How to access a function from within itself in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

In java I can write something like this

```java
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(this);
    }
});
```

When I write something like this in Kotlin I get a compilation error. `this` inside of the lambda expression doesn't work like I expect. What can I do?

```java
val handler = Handler()
handler.post{
    handler.post(this) // this line throws a compilation error
}
```

Comment: `handler.post(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                handler.post(this)
            }
        })` should work

Comment: @TimCastelijns you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val handler = Handler()

fun doAction() {
    handler.post(::doAction) // like `this`
}

handler.post(::doAction)
```

Although technically Tim's solution also works, but he should post it as an answer, as that one is easier. If he does, accept that one instead.

> ```
>     val handler = Handler()
>
>     handler.post(object : Runnable {
>         override fun run() {
>             handler.post(this)
>         }
>     })
> ```

Comment: Thanks. `handler.post(::doAction)` is exactly what I was looking for.